# get currentlogged in users session id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

how to get the logged in current users seesion id? I am using 2.0 version.

I did debug($_Session) and I dont see it there.

```
$this->currentUser = $this->User->find('all',$id);
```

thanks

Comment: did you log this user in? then it would be in `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');`

Comment: What authentication system are you using to log them in? If they're not in the `$_SESSION` var then they're probably not logged in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Cakebook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user):

You can access logged in user using:

```
// Use anywhere
AuthComponent::user('id')
// From inside a controller
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

Comment: This gets the currently logged in users User id, (i.e. The id field from the database table the user is stored in).  @Autolycus asked for the users "Session ID" which is not the same.  If this is the answer, then the question is worded incorrectly.  Otherwise, the Session ID can be obtained with $this->Session->id(); Although an ID  doesn't seem to be set unless you specifically make Cake set one.

Comment: Does this answer apply to CakePHP 1.2?

Comment: This works for me in CakePHP 1.2: `$session->read('Auth.User')`.

Answer (score 13):

You should use SessionComponent to get session_id.
In any Controller you can use it

```
$session_id = $this->Session->id();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

You can also get other data using this way.

```
$this->Auth->user('whatYouWantToGet');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I used session_id() and it gave me what I was looking for. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 1.2, you can use `<?php print_r($session->read('Auth.User'));?>` to print an array that contains the user session ID and more. This is officially documented at https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Authentication.html.